# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes repeatedly

Tags: freeze

I just started having this problem recently, but it will freeze when I am in the middle of coding and it seems to be happening more frequently.

I do tend to have a ton of tabs open in chrome while I am working, but I don't know where to start in seeing what the problem is here.

When it freezes, the mouse will still move but the screen is totally frozen and I have to do a hard reboot. I have tried hotkeys for terminals and other things, but nothing works

Comment: "but I don't know where to start in seeing what the problem is here" Then how can we possibly know what's wrong ? what's your system specs ? Also leave a `system-monitor` visible when it crashes to see if you are overloading CPU or RAM

Answer (score 0):

I started to see exactly the same problem two weeks ago, on my VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 14.04. It could finally solve it by disabling the Mouse Integration feature of VirtualBox. So, if you are running Ubuntu in a VM, the hypervisor could be the problem.

Comment: Not running VM :(